# PubSub between Java and JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, publish-subscribe

is there a good open-source solution to create a PubSub System between Java and JavaScript?

The aim is that the Java System publish a message to JavaScript which is embed into a HTML Page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[CometD](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/)